# What does "height loss" mean on an RNAV (RNP) approach plate?

Tags: instrument-procedures, rnav

While viewing the following approach chart, which is an RNAV(RNP) CAT C Approach, there are several landing minima, stating a HEIGHT LOSS OF 50' AND 150', what does that specifically mean?

[image: RNP APPROACH]

Comment: @Lnafziger - The approach is to the Antonio Narino airport in Colombia, South America.

Answer (score 4):

**The approach above appears to be associated with the Antonio Marino Airport, Colombia, South America:** (I don't know if it is current or proposed)

Descent below the published DA/H is not permitted due to obstacle clearance requirements. Therefore, a "**height loss**" (amount of altitude expected to be lost during a go-around [missed approach]) is added to the minimums to account for this.

The first minimum on the chart is 6240 ft. with a 50 ft height loss added and assumes a missed approach climb gradient of 5%.  The second minimum is 6340 ft. with a 50 ft. height loss added and assumes a climb gradient of 4%.

The 50 ft. added for the height loss is based on the use of a **"radio altimeter."**

The third minimum on the chart is 6340 ft. with a 150 ft. height loss added and assumes a missed approach climb gradient of 5%. The other minimums, all with a 150 ft. height loss added, assume missed approach climb gradients as low as 2.5%.

The 150 ft. added for height loss is based on the use of a **"pressure altimeter."**

---

The chart below is from an advanced version of "Required Navigation Performance Authorization Required (RNP AR) Procedure Design Manual" [ICAO Doc 9905-AN/471](http://code7700.com/pdfs/icao_doc_9905.pdf)

**NOTE**: the added height loss for "radio altimeter" use (category C aircraft) shows 71 ft on the chart below.  The published height loss on the OPs IAP plate shows 50 ft.  I do not know why there is a difference unless the requirements are country localized or the ICAO document has been modified.

[image]

Comment: Good info, but what does the height loss mean?  You don't mention it once in this answer (you kind of imply a meaning in the second section though).  Also, how would you know what your height loss is?

Comment: Right, I get that, but how do I know which set of minimums to use?  The 50 ft. or the 150 ft.?

Comment: @Lnafziger - I modified my answer to address your question/comment above.